# How to properly retrieve users records in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I am trying to retrieve users data from database in **Angular 13**. When I run the code

**it Throws error below**

```
   Error: src/app/users/users.component.ts:31:43 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | undefined): Subscrip
    tion', gave the following error.
        Type '(res: any[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<O
    bserver<Object>>'.
      Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the fol
    lowing error.
        Argument of type '(res: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of ty
    pe '(value: Object) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
            The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to
     use the 'any' type instead?
              Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': l
    ength, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
      Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?
    : ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | un
    defined): Subscription', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '(res: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of ty
    pe '(value: Object) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
            Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
              The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean
    to use the 'any' type instead?
    
        **this.crudservice.getusers().subscribe((res: any[])=>{
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
    
    
    
    **Error: src/app/users/users.component.ts:33:7 - error TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not
     assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    33       this.data = res;
             ~~~~~~~~~**
    
    x Failed to compile.
```

Here is **crude.services.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CrudService {
      userData:any;
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
      //get all users  details
      public getusers()
          {
            
              return this.http.get('http://localhost/getusers.php');
              //alert('ok');
          }
      //add new user      
      public adduser(userData:any)
      {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/insertnew_users.php/'
      , userData).subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.getusers();
      });
      }
        
      
    }
```

Here is **users.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from '../crud.service'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  data = [];
  constructor( private crudservice: CrudService){
    //Get all usera details  
    this.crudservice.getusers().subscribe((res: any[])=>{
          
      this.data = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here is **user.component.html**

```
<div class="container p-5">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       
           
              <tr *ngFor="let user of data">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
              </tr>
           
         
         
          
        </tbody>
      </table>

     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by passing any to data variables as per below

```
  data: any = [];
```

Hence the working code is now

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from '../crud.service'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = [];
  constructor( private crudservice: CrudService){
    //Get all usera details  
    this.crudservice.getusers().subscribe(data =>{
          
      this.data = data;

alert(this.data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```